# Jolt spec to transform fields in selective objects

Tags: json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

For my input json, I need to write a Jolt spec that can modify **manager** attribute by joining the **value & position** fields in only the **user** type object and not the other object type **account**.
The input could be a list of such objects.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "user": {
      "userName": "Mike",
      "manager": {
        "value": "Harvey",
        "position": "Director"
      }
    },
    "account": {
      "userLogin": "Mike1987",
      "status": true
    }
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "userName": "Alex",
      "manager": {
        "value": "Daniel",
        "position": "President"
      }
    },
    "account": {
      "userLogin": "Alex12a",
      "status": true
    }
  }
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
  {
    "user": {
      "userName": "Mike",
      "managerRef": {
        "info": "Harvey_Director"
      }
    },
    "account": {
      "userLogin": "Mike1987",
      "status": true
    }
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "userName": "Alex",
      "managerRef": {
        "info": "Daniel_President"
      }
    },
    "account": {
      "userLogin": "Alex12a",
      "status": true
    }
  }
]
```

Could someone please help in creating the spec for this transformation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **modify** transformation spec which contains a **concat** function such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "user": {
          "manager": {
            "info": "=concat(@(1,value),'_',@(1,position))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
  // get rid of existing attributes within the object
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "u*": {
          "m*": {
            "p*|v*": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

An alternative method which includes a **shift** transformation as desired, based on the comment would be

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "user": {
          "*": "[&2].&1.&",
          "manager": {
            "*": "[&3].&2.&1.info"
          }
        },
        "*": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "user": {
          "manager": {
            "info": "=join('_',@(1,&))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** for this case would be :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Barbaros. If I have to use shift for setting the manager info instead of modify-overwrite-beta, can you tell me how to do it. Since this operation can differ from underscore(_) so I want to understand if this can be done by shift operation as well.
Basically I want to shift data from value & position attributes of manager on left side to info attribute of managerRef on right side.

Comment: Hi @ayan_2587 .  The values of attributes `value` and `position` could be combined within an array by using a `shift` transformation, but in any case, sooner or later we'll need a `modify` transformation to convert them into string type of values.

Comment: Hi Barbaros, Thanks. Can you please share spec on how this could be done using shift transformation.

Comment: OK @ayan_2587 , I've just added the case.

Comment: I have one small query. I understand the use of single & operator. But what does a sequence of & operators mean.. can you pls explain what this means in your solution - [&2].&1.&

Comment: Let me explain starting reversely  @ayan_2587 : `&` for just replication of the current key's value; `&1` stands for going one level up and grabbing the literal `user`; if t was `&2`, then the ouermost indexes `0,1` would return, nesting it within `[]` returns the value array-wise manner rather than object tags tagged `0,1`. Have a nice day.